# SWIG, not able to create typemap for long*

Tags: swig

I have a C function like this one:

```
int make_call(char* to, int *call_id);
```

and a very simple interface file:

```
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "enums.swg"
%include "arrays_java.i"

%header %{
#include <my_header.h>
%}

/* Map "int*" as input & output */
%apply int *INOUT  { int * };
```

This works just fine. In my SWIG file I get:
public static int make_call(String to, int[] call_id) {..}
and I can call it creating an int[] with one element. All good so far.

However as the call_id can be quite large it needs to be a long so I changed this in the C API and I added to the .i file this line:

```
%apply long *OUTPUT  { long * };
```

I have tried several variants including trying to apply what is said in the java.html doc for SWIG but I always end up with an int[] beeing generated or maybe the swigtype for long that I am not able to use from Java. I am just not able to make it generate a long[] that I am expecting.

I tried just making it a double like this:

```
%apply double *OUTPUT  { double * };
```

and it works as expected and I get my double[] call_id in the generated interface.

Is there any pitfalls with the long type? It would seem wierd right?

Comment: I think this depends on your architecture. `long` can also be 32 bit as `int`. Have you tried `long long`? Or better `uint64_t` and `uint32_t`? You can check stdint.h for your architecture, what a 8 Byte integer should be.

Comment: This is currently for Android but the C API must be cross platform so I am not sure if I am going in the right direction here using long then?

Comment: I don't know if Android fully supports C99 standard, if it does than uint64_t is also well defined in stdint.h, which is exactly what you are looking for when defining a cross platform API. So my best bet is, that by including stdint.h into your swig interface and using uint64_t as variable type everything should work out of the box. In case of MSW there is also msinttypes.h on google code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bort. I tried with long long but with the same result. I can get a Swig style variable and if I try to use a typemap I just get an int[]. Even trying to return a plain long as a function result only gives me an int.

Comment: If would be helpful if you state the initial idea of such typemap as I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Alexandre. The only thing I need to do is to pass a pointer to be assigned with the call_id. The issue is that the call_id value might be larger than an int so I would prefer to have a long* in the API instead of an int*. Internally in the C code the call_id value is represented by a long so I just wanted to maintain that mapping but right now I am casting the long into an int before passing it back to Java over the JNI.

Comment: Ok, so see my reply below. I not sure for what platform you develop, but on x86/amd64 size of "long" equals to the size of "int" and both equal to 4 bytes. I think this is the reason why SWIG wraps "long" with "int" - Java's long has the size of 8 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try one of:

```
unsigned long
unsigned int
long long
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tested these a while back but I must have made a mistake. Finally the long long produces a long[] in Java which is what I look for. I end up with this:
%apply long long *OUTPUT { long *call_id };